# Find Device Locations using android UUID

Tags: cordova, geolocation, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, uuid

I'm using ionic framework to develop my application. Is it possible to use a device's UUID number to get its' location?

I have different UUID of different device, I want to locate all the device in google map. Location once device in map based on android UUID is also fine. I'm new to phonegap. Can you please guide me to find out this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible to get it from device UUID, but you can use following plugin to get location of your app user and save it in database on  onDeviceReady event. hope it helps.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable answer. I hope i may work for me.